# Is SessionAffinity in kubernetes Azure for external clients

Tags: azure, kubernetes, load-balancing

I'm struggling to find documentation on this.
I wish to have this service spec:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: API1
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
  - name: port1
    port: 80
  selector:
    app: API1
  sessionAffinityConfig:
    clientIP:
      timeoutSeconds: 30
```

API1 has 3 replicas.

One of my deployments in the same cluster (API2) uses this API1. Would this config also result in all traffic from API2 to the same pod in API1? That would be undesirable.

Comment: Which version of Kubernetes did you use and how did you set up the cluster?

Comment: I'm using k8s version 1.20.9. The cluster was setup via .bicep files and configured via .yaml files. I hope this is what you meant.

Comment: I've done some research to your issue, could you please attach also your second deployment (API2) so it could be reproduced? (How API2 uses API1?) Also [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#:~:text=If%20you%20want,be%203%20hours).) is explanation about `sessionAffinityConfig`.